# Unhandeled exception when adding sprite in cocos2d in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

> Unhandled exception at 0x0096348B in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

this is the error i get when trying to use a Sprite i added.

```
CCSprite *sprite = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("Untitled.png" );
sprite->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero);
this->addChild(sprite, -1);
```

Error is at first line

Thanks for your help.

am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: what's the line where this error occurs?

Comment: Where is "Untitled.png" placed? It should be directly in "Resources" folder.

Comment: If your file cannot be found by cocos2d-x, it will throw an exception...debug down into the code and I suspect you will find it is throwing on the file load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Try! this it works for me.
  CCSize screenSize   = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
        pointOrigin  = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();
        x = screenSize.width;
        y = screenSize.height;


    CCSprite* sprite=CCSprite::create("icon.png");
        sprite->setPosition(ccp(x/2,y/2));
        addChild(sprite,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting because you might have copied `Untitled.png` in your `Resources` directory but for Windows Phone 8 you have to add reference of this file to your project. You can just right click on project and add existing image file. Simple copy paste won't work with WP8. That why you are getting NULL while creating Sprite object.